# Should I change the value of anchors in yolo-obj.cfg?

Tags: yolo

I am trying to re-train yolo with custom dataset according to [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects).
Now I'm rewriting yolov3-tiny-obj.cfg but can I rewrite value of anchors with only value of filter and class number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to re-calculate the anchors based on your custom dataset as well.

For normal Yolo V3 with 9 anchors (416 is the size of your yolo model, could be 320, 608, etc) use

```
./darknet detector calc_anchors data/obj.data -num_of_clusters 9 -width 416 -height 416
```

For Tiny Yolo V3 with 6 anchors use

```
./darknet detector calc_anchors data/obj.data -num_of_clusters 6 -width 416 -height 416
```

Then replace the `anchors` value in your cfg file with the new generated value. Don't forget to change the `class` and `filters` value as well.

Comment: For Yolo-Lite? How could I set num_of_clusters parameter?

Comment: @BarzanHayati Alexey's and original repo dont have yolo lite if I remember correctly, what repo are you using?

Comment: I use original darknet repos: Pjrediee, yolo lite is a new version and is not in alexeyab repos.

Comment: Funny enough, if you use the above application on the original data that were used to generate yoloV3 anchors (COCO 2014/2017 according to my understanding), you don't obtain the actual anchors put in the cfg file.

Comment: How do you pick the number of anchors? Is it defined somewhere? Is 6 and 9 arbitrary? Is more better?

Comment: @PNDA it is defined in original YOLO paper